# Why double quotes when using map (imploding) for an array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, implode

I have an array that I want to translate into a string

```
100
110
120
145
```

I want this result/output:

```
"100","110","120","145"
```

I tried:

```
var send_data_ids = $.map( ids_above, function( n ) {
    return String.fromCharCode(34) + n + String.fromCharCode(34);
});
```

But then I get double quotations. Why?

```
""100"",""110"",""120"",""145""
```

Comment: Because you use `String.fromCharCode(34)`, maybe ;D Take it out and it should work properly.

Comment: @Al.G. - it's the same issue when I use '"' + n + '"'. Or what am I supposed to use?

Comment: Don't use anything, just return `n`. And I'm not sure why do you even have to do this `.map()`.

Comment: LOL. Thank you! Sometimes... hm...

Comment: I want that format to send an array of values towards an external api that requires those quotes round each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.map` will return another array, if you want a string just use:

```
var x = ["100","110","120","145"];
var y = "\""+x.join("\",\"")+"\"";
```

or in your code do

```
var send_data_ids = $.map( ids_above, function( n ) {
    return String.fromCharCode(34) + n + String.fromCharCode(34);
});
var y = "\""+send_data_ids.join(",")+"\"";
```

Comment: Or just remove String.fromCharCode(34) as stated in comments :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the options! :-)